# Smallest unused id python if condition error

Tags: python

```
def next_id(arr):
    if arr:
        arr.sort()
        if arr[0] != 0:
            return 0
        for i in range(len(arr)):
            if (arr[i]-arr[i+1])<-1:
                return arr[i]+1
            else:
                return arr[len(arr)-1]+1
    else:
        return 0
```

I'm trying to find the Smallest unused ID, and for some reason its not entering this if condition:

```
if (arr[i]-arr[i+1])<-1:
```

when I try this

```
next_id([0,1,2,3,5]
```

for test it returns 6 instead of 4.

Comment: Please fix the formatting. The if/else is not indented correctly.

Comment: Could you provide an example for `arr`?

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Hmm...how about use `min(set(range(min(arr), max(arr))) - set(arr))` instead? So `set(range(min(arr), max(arr))) - set(arr)` gets all the unused ids, and `min()` picks the smallest one.

Comment: @KevinGuan: that will get very inefficient if there is a large gap between used ids, e.g. `arr = [0,1,2,3,1000]`, due to generating the `range()` and performing the set operations on that large range.

Comment: I got it guys, thank you so much !
Its a kata from codewars.com and for whos asking for some exemples for arr here it is:
next_id([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
next_id([5,4,3,2,1])
next_id([0,1,2,3,5])
next_id([0,0,0,0,0,0])
next_id([])

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your function *always* exits on the first loop of `for`: the difference is `-1` for the first iteration of array `[0, 1, 2, 4, 5]`; and the `else` branch is run; and that returns the largest id + 1 right away.

Thus this code should be executed only *after* the loop completes:

```
def next_id(arr):
    if not arr:
        return 0

    arr.sort()
    if arr[0] != 0:
        return 0

    for i in range(len(arr) - 1):
        if arr[i] - arr[i + 1] < -1:
            return arr[i] + 1

    return arr[-1] + 1
```

Notice that the end index need to be adjusted as well - instead of iterating to `len(arr)` we can only iterate to `len(arr) - 1`, because otherwise `arr[i + 1]` would be out of bounds.

---

And if you want to write more concisely, the same algorithm can be written as

```
def next_id(arr):
    return next(i for i, j in enumerate(sorted(arr) + [None]) if i != j)
```

Answer (score 2):

How bout this?

```
def next_id(arr):
    arr = sorted(set(arr))
    # arr = sorted([x for x in set(arr) if type(x) is int]) # If you want a more tolerance
    if arr[0] != 0:
        return 0
    for i, v in enumerate(arr):
        if i != v:
            return i
    return i+1
```

It just iterates through each position and returns the index if it doesn't match. I added the set() in case of duplicates.

```
arr[0] = 0
arr[1] = 1
arr[2] = 2
arr[3] = 3
arr[4] = 5 # => UH OH! Return 4
```

So:

```
print(next_id([0,1,2,3,5])) # => 4
print(next_id([0,1,2,3,4,5])) # => 6
print(next_id([7,1,3,7,1,4,2,3,4,7,0,9,9,2,3,7,0,9,6,5])) # => 8
```

Comment: I quite like this approach, but why did you change the OP's PEP8 compliant function name into a non-compliant one?

Comment: @mhawke What can I say? I'm a rebel.

Comment: ... or a reformed java programmer? Ahh, that's better.

Comment: I honestly never liked Java. I'm moving to C++ and keeping with Python, now :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `for` loop, you have this structure:

```
for ...:
    if ...:
        return ...
    else ...:
        return ...
```

This means that the `for` loop is guaranteed to return on its first iteration. Try a structure like this instead:

```
for ...:
    if ...:
        return ...
return ...
```

This structure will take the first return if the `if` is ever satisfied, and will take the second return if the `if` is never satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
def next_id(arr):
if arr:
    arr.sort()
    if arr[0] != 0:
        return 0
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if (arr[i]-arr[i+1])<-1:
            return arr[i]+1
    return arr[len(arr)-1]+1
else:
    return 0
```

print(next_id([0,1,2,3,5]))

Answer (score 0):

funny, I was just doing simple kata on codewars and while looking how to solve the problem I found this post. I've managed to solve it and that's the code I used:

```
def next_id(arr):
for i in range(len(arr)+1):
    if i not in arr:
        return I
```

Hope that helps. range(len(arr)+1) required as If you would have a list [1,2,3]
next available is [4] (out of list) so you need to make your list a bit longer just in case.